# Ruby, create hash from MySQL2::result object that I can pluck data out of

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, mysql2

I have a MySQL2::Result object `@available_items` and

```
@available_items.each do |row| puts row.values.join("\t   ") end
```

gives me something that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
|    tdate   |   whatDay    |              items               |
+------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
| 2018-01-02 |    Tuesday   |    OL,BD,DM,WW,DG                |
| 2018-01-03 |    Wednesday |    KP,LW                         |
| 2018-01-04 |    Thursday  |    LW,WW,FS,DG                   |
| 2018-01-05 |    Friday    |    OL,KP,BD,SB,LW,DM,AS,WW,FS,DG |
| 2018-01-06 |    Saturday  |    OL,KP,BD,SB,LW,DM,AS,WW,FS,DG |
+------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

Well, actually it looks like something else, but hopefully you get the idea.

I know that the default MySQL2 results output is as a hash, but I cannot figure out how to be able to refer to the items in column 3 by reference to the date in column 1 (i.e. use `tdate` as `key` to get `items` as `value`.)

So I created some, what feels like, "dirty" code with a pluck method to create an array

```
@available_items.each do |row|
@available_array[0] = @available_items.pluck("tdate")
@available_array[1] = @available_items.pluck("whatDay")
@available_array[2] = @available_items.pluck("items")
end
```

Now I have an array where I can call by reference to the array, but what I really want is a `hash` where `tdate` is the key and `items` is the value, so that later on I can pull one of the (abbreviated) items out of the comma separated list in `items` for any given date at random and put that single item into a new hash (pseudocode) and then examine that hash using some other code.

```
@final_list = hash.new()
@final_list[:tdate] = items(randomSelection)
```

If I try to create a hash as follows:

```
@available_hash = Hash.new()
@available_items.each do |row|
@keyis = @available_items.pluck("tdate")
@valueis = @available_items.pluck("available")
@available_hash[@keyis] = @valueis
end
```

and then do

```
@available_hash.each_with_index do |k, v| puts "#{k} : #{v}" end
```

I get:

```
[[#<Date: 2018-01-02 ((2458121j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2018-01-03 ((2458122j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2018-01-04 ((2458123j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2018-01-05 ((2458124j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2018-01-06 ((2458125j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>], nil] : 0
```

which looks like it has just fed everything into one line.

I have a feeling I am trying to be too complex, and also that I have misunderstood how to append to a hash.

So the question is: how do I create hash where each `{key,value}` pair of things looks like `{tdate: items}` with one new pair for each date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@available_hash = @available_items.map{|item| [item["date"], item["items"]] }.to_h
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't quite work, but `@available_hash = @available_items.map do
  |h| {h["tdate"] => h["available"] }
end` did.

Comment: @busfender Great to hear that. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as a more obvious answer than being buried in comments:

```
@available_hash = @available_items.map do |h| {h["tdate"] => h["available"] } end
```